# Simplest way to do add/remove of model relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, form-for

I am wondering what the best way to do a small update to my models is. What I mean is that I would like to have a button that created or destroyed a relationship between two of my models through a has_many :through relationship. So I have Users, Dvds, Queues, and DvdQueues.

I want to add a simple button to a lot of the pages that when clicked, adds a Dvd to the Users Queue. What is the best way to accomplish this? Should I load up a simple form on each page? Should I link the button to a controller action that handles it? If I do use a form, do I need  nested attributes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add action `add_dvd` to your necessary controller and use `button_to`([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)) helper. Also you can use ajax. Just add `remote: true` option to button and work with `add_dvd` and handle your response :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would to be use a separate controller for the DvdQueues with just the create/destroy actions, and then in the view using link_to with [the Rails javascript-helper :method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) (:post|:delete in this case)

For instance:

```
class DvdQueuesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # params[:dvd_queue] = {"dvd_id": x, "queue_id": y}
    @user.dvd_queues.create params[:dvd_queue]
    redirect_to dvds_path
  end

  def destroy
    dvd_que = @user.dvd_queues.find_by_id params[:id]
    dvd_que.destroy
    redirect_to dvds_path
  end
end
```

```
module DvdQueuesHelper
  def link_to_add_or_remove_from_queue(dvd, text)
    if @user.dvd_queues.exists? :dvd_id => dvd.id
      link_to text, dvd_queues_path(dvd.id), :method => :delete
    else
      link_to text, dvd_queues_path, :method => :post
    end
  end
end
```